# Is this QR code in Fez useful?

Tags: fez

There's a QR code in 16-cubes city but it has been blocked by some obstacle.

[image: in-game incomplete image]

And I tried to fix the picture to make it clearer but there's still something missing in the top left part.

[image: removed the scaffolding blocking parts of the code]

You can clean that up further and replace the missing parts that are unfinished but known:

[image: black-and-white QR code with some missing pixels placed]

But it still doesn't scan.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: As a note, you can't just "clean up" and "replace missing parts" of 2d and barcodes. That's encoded information, swapping one pixel can change the contained information of the code. Reconstruction of damaged (like this one) 2d and barcodes is *hard* and more of brute force nature.

Comment: @Bobby: It's missing less than one quarter, most of which was the position, format, and timing indicators, all of which are redundant data and can easily be replaced. The remaining missing data comprises an easily brute-forceable number of bits. At _minimum_ a QR code can have 7% of its words corrupted and still be perfectly recoverable.

Comment: After you start a new game plus you get an extra ability that'll help with viewing the obstructed codes!

Answer (score 20):

The 16-cube area is the ancient version of the temple/science warp zone. That QR code was under construction long ago, but it now appears "fully realized" on the same wall in the temple/science warp zone. So it can be completed—indeed, it has been.

[image: QR code from temple/science warp zone]

If you're curious, the QR code links to...

> text: "RT RT LT RT LT LT LT RT" (which triggers an anticube, as shown above)

This is a higher resolution of the screenshot, from the PC gersion of the game:
[image: Complete QR code on a screenshot]

I have then extracted the QR code, converted it to black and white, removed Gomez and some dust, and applied a median filter. This is the complete QR code, which you can scan [on a website](http://scanner.code-qr.net/).

[image: Complete QR code extracted]

Comment: Are you sure it can't be completed? The number of missing elements is very small and all the format data is available. Seems like we're missing maybe 20-30 bits...

Comment: It isn't meant to be completed by us—it's more of a plot continuity thing

Comment: This QR Code is linked to the Monocle Room (Fezzes Painting) in the first village.

Comment: How do you read this QR code? I cannot get anything from [mine](http://i.imgur.com/rON8JvV.png).

Comment: @wok: You use a QR reader/scanner app, or just scan one of the images at the top of the screen. Remember that the code shows twice—once incomplete and once complete. The QR reader/scanner will return an input code (which is grayed out in a spoiler box beneath my answer). Sound good?

Comment: Could you point to one available for PC? The ones I have found on Internet do not return anything for this image, although it is the same image as in your answer. See: http://i.imgur.com/rON8JvV.png

Comment: @wok: You mean for scanning a PC screenshot? Because a QR reader is like a barcode scanner—you'll need a phone. Anyway, I don't know of one for PC, but I already did the work for you in the spoiler box above (so you don't really even need it).

Comment: Yes, your code worked fine, it is just there are several QR codes in the game, and if I cannot do it for this one, then I won't be able to use any of the QR code by myself.

Comment: Okay, I had to resize the QR code so that it fits in 400x400 pixels. This was my problem: the high resolution of a PC screenshot. This website gives the result: http://scanner.code-qr.net/

Comment: Yeah, its the same as the one in the ruint city. Funnily enough, the missing piece is recoverable on its own. I gave it a shot, adding in the 3rd corner marker, and the 0/1 lines that run along the top and left hand sides, and it didn't work. Tried again, this time infilling the remaining blank spaces with a checkerboard pattern as per the suggestion in game (see the poster on the wall). Worked perfectly. Was _just_ within the acceptable redundancy threshold.

Answer (score 4):

I finished the game and found the completed QR code. After I scanned it it's  #F0493E, which is a hex color for a shade of red. I want to say it has something to do with the 3 red rooms and the 3 missing pieces of the heart puzzle...but I have no way of proving that.

Answer (score 2):

The code translates to RT RT LT RT LT LT LT RT. 
If you push d d a d a a a d you get an anticube